# How do I use `node-sass-asset-functions` custom functions with Laravel Mix?

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp, laravel-mix

I am trying to make SASS functions provided by `node-sass-asset-functions` available for use in Sass that's compiled with Laravel Mix. If I was using Gulp, I'd pass-in `functions` to `sass.render` like this:

```js
const assetFunctions  = require('node-sass-asset-functions');

gulp.task('sass:dev:compile', function () {
  return gulp.src([sassSrcPath])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      functions: assetFunctions({
        images_path: './images'
      }),
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(sassDestPath));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the result of requiring the module into the `functions` option of `mix.sass`:

```js
const assetFunctions = require('node-sass-asset-functions');

mix.sass('src/sass/styles.scss', 'css', {
  functions: assetFunctions({
    images_path: './images'
  })
});
```